# Rstudio crashes when using interacting with ggplotly plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, rstudio, plotly

I am trying to plot outliers in a boxplot with large data-sets for interactive use with plotly.  To make plotting of a large number of points practical, the goal is to use geom_jitter with geom_count functionality (i.e. area of plotted points to denote count of points).  In a shiny app, zooming into the region would result in geom_count being run again and new jittered points being shown.

In trying the run the following minimal example, RStudio crashes.  I have ggplot2 from github or from CRAN.  Either Rstudio 0.99 or the latest version.  Latest version of plotly or previous version of plotly.  All eight combinations crash Rstudio when I try to interactively use the resulting plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

fa <- data.frame(qsec = boxplot.stats(mtcars$qsec)$out)

fb <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes("qsec", qsec)) + 
       geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
       geom_count(data = fa, aes("qsec", qsec ))
fb
ggplotly(fb)

fc <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes("qsec", qsec)) + 
       geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
       geom_jitter(data = fa, aes("qsec", qsec ))
fc
ggplotly(fc)

fd <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes("qsec", qsec)) + 
       geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
       geom_point(data = fa, aes("qsec", qsec ))
fd
ggplotly(fd)
```

The ggplot's are fine.  ggplotly plots are fine.  The issue arises when I interact with the plot after plotting, which is when RStudio crashes (e.g. while zooming).  Alternate approaches or a fix would be greatly useful.

Comment: Cannot confirm, zoom works fine, `packageVersion("plotly")` is `‘4.7.1.9000’`.

Comment: @lukeA - In plotly, after magnifying in viewer (i.e. zooming), try Autoscale.  There will be an error and Rstudio "has stopped working"

Comment: Oh, true. However, I dunno how to cure that. In fact, RStudio quite often crashes on my machine when plotly or also shiny come into play...

Comment: Are you opening it in browser or the Rstudio viewer?

Comment: @amrrs - Got similar behavior when I tried it in both (Viewer with example above) and in browser as a Shinyapp (with desktop shiny package)

Comment: Try adding `options(viewer=NULL) ` in the first line of your code.

Comment: @Marco Sandri - options(viewer=NULL) results in a plot that is similar to the ggplot solution.  However, this is insufficient because the goal is to have an interactive plot where one can create agglomerates that unravel on zooming into the (millions of) potential outlier(s) - so, one can focus on a data-point at the end.